# Fail and cease tests on predicate failure in clojure.test

Tags: clojure

If any step in my test setup fails, I want to report this as a failure, and cease any subsequent tests in the current `deftest` block (or current namespace). One way to do this now:

```
(if some-condition-is-ok
  (do
    ... do tests)
  (is (= 1 0) "Failure, condition not met")
```

The above:

1. Reports failure if `some-condition-is-ok` is not met
2. Does not run any tests, since the setup condition was not met

Except that it does not flow well, and does not work well for multiple conditions. I'd like something like:

```
(let [;; setup here...]

  (assert-or-stop-tests some-condition-is-ok)
  ... continue with tests here
```

Any ideas on a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Mark Engelberg's [better-cond](https://github.com/Engelberg/better-cond/tree/v1.0.1) for this:

```
(require '[better-cond.core :as b]
         '[clojure.test :refer [is]])

(def some-condition-is-ok true)

(def some-other-condition-is-ok false)

(deftest a-test
  (b/cond
    :let [#_"setup here..."]
    :when (is some-condition-is-ok)
    :let [_ (is (= 0 1))]
    :when (is some-other-condition-is-ok)
    :let [_ (is (= 1 2))]))
```

Or if you want to avoid the `:let [_ ,,,]`, you could define your own macro:

```
(defmacro ceasing [& exprs]
  (when-let [[left & [right & less :as more]] (seq exprs)]
    (if (= :assert left)
      `(when (is ~right)
         (ceasing ~@less))
      `(do
         ~left
         (ceasing ~@more)))))

(deftest b-test
  (let [#_"setup here..."]
    (ceasing
      :assert some-condition-is-ok
      (is (= 0 1))
      :assert some-other-condition-is-ok
      (is (= 1 2)))))
```

Comment: It seems like a decent candidate as it has no dependencies other than clojure core, though I still don't like the `:let` binding appearance.  Upvoting because it's a reasonable option, thanks for your answer Sam

Comment: @Josh I've updated my answer to address both of your comments. Previously it did have a dependency other than Clojure core (namely, better-cond), but I've rewritten the `ceasing` macro without better-cond, as well as removing the `:let` bindings.

Comment: Thanks Sam -- I will leave this open for a bit to encourage other answers but wanted to go ahead and thank you for modifying it